# Temporary Signed URL won't work if APP_URL contains port in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel

This is weird because if I don't have `:3000` in my `APP_URL`, it works fine.

```
  $url = URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'verification.verify', Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), ['user' => $notifiable->id]
        );

        return $url;
```

```
APP_URL=https://shadow-platform.test:3000
```

```
Route::get('email/verify/{user}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you’ll need to add the new `ValidateSignature` to your route middleware in `/app/Http/Kernel.php`.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
         // ...
         'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
+        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
         'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
```

Then you should apply ->middleware('signed') to your route

```
Route::get('email/verify/{user}', 'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify')->middleware('signed');
```

Comment: Are you using PHP's built-in development server (php artisan serve) ?

Comment: I am using Laravel Valet.

Comment: By default the HTTP-server will listen to port 8000. I'm not familiar with Laravel Valet , however, i guess you could specify what port to use.